# Summing multiple rows with duplicate values Python

Tags: python, pandas

Have for me what is a wide data frame (67) columns, (30) are float and 37 are object or date. Finding duplicate column values for one of the objects that should be a foreign key for me to join to another data set.

Looking for a group by agg solution to keep first instance of all object/date columns while summing of all float columns.

Must be a way to optimize code to to avoid  df.grupby([('insert 37 variables'], as_index=False)['insert 30 variables'].sum()

The initial data set looks like this

[image]

And the resulting data set should look like

[image]

Here is basic code I was starting with, but thinking there must be a better way, does not appear I can use a lamda function given the mix of variables, pivot would also require listing all variables, I looked at iloc and loc as well, this must be something others deal with regularly have not been able to find a online solution.

df = df.groupby(['account_number','policy_number', 'other varibales to 37'],
as_index=False)['internal_expense','external_expense','other variables to 30'].sum()

Comment: What's wrong with `groupby` and then `sum`? Maybe store the desired columns in two variables, so your code looks less cluttered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `select_dtypes`:

```
obj = df.select_dtypes(exclude='number').columns.tolist()
num = df.select_dtypes(include='number').columns.tolist()
out = df.groupby(obj, as_index=False)[num].sum()
print(out)

# Output
  account_number policy_number  revenue  internal_expense  external_expense
0           1234          1234       26                 3                 1
1           1235          1237       10                 0                 0
```

**Update** if all object / numeric columns are correctly organized (ones to left, others to right), you can slice the dataframe:

```
left = df.columns[:2].tolist()
right = df.columns[2:].tolist()
out = df.groupby(left, as_index=False)[right].sum()
```

Input:

```
data = {'account_number': ['1234', '1234', '1234', '1235'],
        'policy_number': ['1234', '1234', '1234', '1237'],
        'revenue': [20, 5, 1, 10],
        'internal_expense': [0, 1, 2, 0],
        'external_expense': [0, 1, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# Output
  account_number policy_number  revenue  internal_expense  external_expense
0           1234          1234       20                 0                 0
1           1234          1234        5                 1                 1
2           1234          1234        1                 2                 0
3           1235          1237       10                 0                 0
```

Comment: Did not think of creating a list, nice and simple.  Was able to aggregate across 94 duplicate observations, still finding I have 61 non unique values.  Trying to understand what would prevent those observation from summing, is it a question that there are inconsistent values across other columns for those 61 observations I.e account_number is the same but some of the other 29 object columns are different across rows? I did order my dataframe so I can try method 2 but don't see how that would make a difference.

Comment: It makes no difference between two methods. Try `out.value_counts(obj)` to get more information about count of unique groups.